# How to maintain the integrity of json when a program end abruptly python

Tags: python, json

I'm running 'multiple threads' in one script that open 10 children. Each child script queries an API and logs some data into a json. I make a log of each json saved in another json, however the code sometimes ends abruptly and destroys the integrity of the json so it can't be re-opened eg:

```
["2016_02_21_18_46_41", 1], ["2016_02_21_18_46_42", 1], ["2016_02_21_18_46_4
```

How can make it so it only writes the data to the json if it's complete? or how can I alternatively fix this problem ?

For continuity, here if my parent script

```
from threading import Thread
import sys

sys.path.append('/python/loanrates/master')

names =  ['BTS', 'ETH', 'CLAM', 'DOGE', 'FCT', 'MAID', 'STR', 'XMR', 'XRP', 'BTC' ]
threads = []
for name in names: 
    sys.path.append('/python/loanrates/'+name)

import Master

for name in names:
    T = Thread(target=Master.main, args=(name,))
    print T
    threads.append(T)

for thread_ in threads:
    thread_.start()

for thread_ in threads:
    thread_.join()
```

and here is my child script

```
import arrow
import json
import pickle  
import time
import urllib

def main(name):

    date = arrow.utcnow().format('YYYY_MM_DD_HH_mm_ss')
    previous_date = "2016_02_18_09_02_52"
    previous_second = date[-2:]
    count = 0

    print name,'has started'

    while True:
            date = arrow.utcnow().format('YYYY_MM_DD_HH_mm_ss')
            second = int(date[-2:])
            url = 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnLoanOrders&currency='+name
            try:
                response = urllib.urlopen(url)
                data = json.loads(response.read())
            except:
                data = 'error'
                print 'error wth name has occured, probably been blocked by polo'
                time.sleep(10)

            #open previous data
            with open( 'D:/python/loanrates/'+name+'/'+previous_date+'.json', 'r') as f:
                previous_data = json.load(f)

            #open date log
            with open( 'D:/python/loanrates/'+name+'/date_store.json', 'r') as f:
                date_store = json.load(f)

            #compare new to old data
            # if new != old, new data is saved and that date recives a 1 in the 'date_store' dict,
            # signifying theres is new data for that date
            if previous_data != data and previous_second != second and second%10 == 0:

                date_store.append((date,1))

                with open( 'D:/python/loanrates/'+name+'/'+date+'.json', 'w') as f:
                    json.dump(data, f)

                with open( 'D:/python/loanrates/'+name+'/date_store.json', 'w') as f:
                    json.dump(date_store, f)

                previous_date = date
                previous_second = second

                count += 1
                if count == 1000: print 'name has logged 1000'
            # if new = old the new data hasn't changed and isn't saved, that date 'date_store' recieves a 0
            # signifying that the previous date of value 1 can be subtituted for this date
            elif previous_second != second and second%10 == 0:
                date_store.append((date,0))

                with open( 'D:/python/loanrates/'+name+'/date_store.json', 'w') as f:
                    json.dump(date_store, f)

                previous_second = second

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main(name)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print 'Interrupted'
        try:
            sys.exit(0)
        except SystemExit:
            os._exit(0)
    except:
        pass
```

(as you can see there is only one child script but it's in a for loop)

Comment: post the external code INTO stackoverflow

Comment: It's a bit long is that still allowed ?

Comment: you can use `try/except` to solve this problem

Comment: But when the program ends abruptly the json is incomplete, so this must mean it it happens during the saving of the json ? I'm assuming. Having a try: json dump wouldn't work in my opinion because the 'try' would be accepted then the program crashes and the problem is still at large @shafeen

Comment: @DavidHancock why does your program crash?  Fix the crash and you won't have invalid output.  (note that this is not specific to json, it applies to any output that is incomplete when a program crashes or aborts)

Answer (score 0):

try/except should work if you keep a backup file on successful loading when the data is not corrupted. Then when trying to load json load the backup file when it goes to exception

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Consider increasing the level of detail and clarity in this answer by adding example code.  This will likely improve the clarity of the above answer you've given.